Replace URLs with Buttons in wpDataTables Exported Table Using JavaScript
I'm working with the wpDataTables plugin on a WordPress site and trying to replace URLs with buttons in one of my tables. Specifically, I have columns that contain Instagram and YouTube links, and I want these to appear as "Open" buttons that, when clicked, open the link in a new tab.
I added the following JavaScript code to my hello-frontend.min.js file to try and replace the links with buttons:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // Custom code to replace links with buttons
  document.querySelectorAll('td.column-instagram a, td.column-youtube a').forEach(function(link) {
    const url = link.getAttribute('href');
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    button.textContent = 'Open';
    button.className = 'button-color';
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      window.open(url, '_blank');
    });
    link.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the link
    link.appendChild(button); // Append the button
  });
});

After deploying this code, the links still appear as plain URLs in the table.
Why are the URLs not being replaced by buttons, and how can I ensure the links are properly replaced by the buttons? Is there a better approach for modifying the content of the table rows generated by wpDataTables?
Thank you very much for any help!:)
I reviewed the documentation of the wpDataTables plugin and found that there is an option to display links as buttons. However, when I enable this feature and export the table, the exported file shows the button label (e.g., "Open") instead of the actual URL. I want the buttons to be displayed in the table but retain the correct link format in exports. To solve this, I tried replacing the links with custom buttons using JavaScript, but it hasn't worked as expected.

Just an update - managed to fix it:)
